# BOLT: listing_records not working?

Tags: bolt-cms

I am trying to display 24 products in frontend on this page: http://stage.softoven.com/meubleshouse/categories/lighting

I have set the `listing_records: 24` in the content type of `products` but it doesn't seem to work accordingly. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it. It was not the `contenttypes.yml` file but it was `taxonomy.yml` file where I had to update `listing_records: 24`.

I hope it will help someone in future.